# Use -Xfatal-warnings but ignore deprecation warnings / Custom reporter using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

As the title states, what I'm *really* trying to do is be able to turn on `-Xfatal-warnings` except for deprecation warnings. It seems that this can be done with custom reporters as shown in https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4544. As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4544#issuecomment-121707235) on that PR, SBT already overrides the reporter so using that option is ignored. I was wondering how to use a custom reporter while using SBT? I'm currently using SBT 1.1.1, but am happy to upgrade for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this. This has been solved by direct support in Scalac in versions 2.12.13 and 2.13.2 and newer. See this blog post: [Configuring and suppressing warnings in Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html).